# Can't open CSV file even with full file path

Tags: python, csv

I'm using Python 3.5 and I'm having some problems opening a CSV file. I've tried entering the entire path but it still doesn't work, but the file is clearly in the folder. (My code is called 'simplecsvtest.py')

Here's the code snippet:

```
import csv
import sys

file = open(r"C:\python35\files\results.csv", 'rt')

try:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    ... some code here ...

finally:
    file.close()
```

And here's what PowerShell says:

```
PS C:\python35\files> python simplecsvtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simplecsvtest.py", line 20, in 
    file = open(r"C:\python35\files\results.csv", 'rt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\python35\\files\\results.csv'
```

Well, I'm very certain that 'results.csv' is in that folder: here's the filepath in Windows Explorer:

```
C:\Python35\files
```

(Note: The folder has capital 'P' for Python35, and I've tried having both capitalized and uncapitalized 'P' in the code, neither works)

The CSV file is a "Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values Files", if that matters, but the extension is still csv. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Windows filesystems aren't case-sensitive, so casing shouldn't be an issue. Do you get the same result if you use forward slashes for the path? Can you open the file manually (e.g. `cat "C:\python35\files\results.csv"` from PowerShell)? Is the directory a symlink/junction?

Comment: I guess the problem are hidden filename extensions. So even if the file is displayed as `results.csv` it might have an additional (hidden) extension (for example also `.csv`, so the actual filename would be `results.csv.csv`). You probably renamed this file from `results` to `results.csv`, retaining the actual (hidden) extension. Check [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/) on how to always show the file extension as part of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a folder inside your project folder and then use a relative path :

file = open(r".\files\results.csv", 'rt')

. implies that the path is relative to your current directory

Comment: also check permissions on the file

Comment: Hmm. I gave that a try too but for some reason the same error pops up... Also I checked permissions on the file, I should have full access/editing + I've launched Powershell as Administrator. However I did find a little workaround (see my own answer). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work-around solution myself:
Somehow, if I copy all the data from the csv and paste it in a new excel spreadsheet and save it as a csv, it works. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Although the file path is absolute it wouldn't work this way.
You have to use "forward" slashes in the path name instead of "backward" slashes. As

```
file = open(r"C:/python35/files/results.csv", 'rt')
```